# timestamp without time zone >= bytea

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to pass dates in native query in Jpa Repository. I tried a lot of thing like passing dates, strings but unable to make query work. I am new to Jpa Repository. 
I tried this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_native_queries

but there, they didn't give example for date. I am giving following code for what i need:

```
@Query(value ="select * from \"order\" ord where ord.agent_id = :agentId and ord.order_date >= :startDate order by ?#{#pageable}", nativeQuery = true)
Page findByAgentId(@Param("agentId") Long agentId, @Param("startDate") String startDate, Pageable pageable);
```

Error is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone >= bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

and, I am using postgres as DB.